# Which unit of measurement does SetForce() use?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello evryone, I have a model of a quadrotor in matlab and to stabilize it at a fixed height I need a thrust of 6,3 N. I also have a simple model of the same quadrotor in gazebo controlled through a PD and it appears that the force applyed to stabilize it is 62.7, is it possible that the force is computed in 100*mN ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11392/which-unit-of-measurement-does-setforce()-use?/) by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-10-03

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [ROS standard](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#units) for that. It should be Newtons.

Perhaps that model is not in compliance with REP-0103?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on 2011-10-03**:
didn't know about ROS standard but it seems that the model is still compliant with REP-0103.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I menaged to solve the problem: the frequency of the controller was lower then the stepTime of the .world file thus the controller needed to apply a higher force in order to keep the quadrotor floating.

---

Originally posted by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) with karma: 111 on 2011-10-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1